# 'Expected a key while parsing a block mapping' in the pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart

### i am beginner in flutter.

i want to use asset image in my project, i created folder named
*assets* and pasted the image in it.

i just followed the instructor steps and i modified the *pubspec* file.

### the file was as this:

```
uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
```

**i just uncommented and modified to my image path as this :**

```
uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
   assets:
    - assets/type1.png
```

when i pushed run button this error happened to me :

> Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
>
> Error on line 44, column 4: Expected a key while parsing a block
>   mapping.
>   ╷
>
> 44 │    assets:
>
> │    ^
>
> ╵

**note :**
this was the first modification in the *pubspec* file.

Answer (score 3):

space and indent is meaningful in YAML

```
  #  - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #  - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
  assets:
    - assets/images/
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `assets` needs to be aligned with the key `uses-material-design`, `.yaml` files work on indentation of the code inside them after properly indenting the code I think it should work.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a combined version of both **@chunhunghan** and **@Kushagra Saxena** Answers(for better understanding)

When you first try to add the asset folder to the `pubspec.yaml` file there are two options.

1. Uncomment the existing code and edit it the way you wanted.
2. Delete or keep the commented asset section and add a new one yourself.

Initially the section(asset section of `pubspec.yaml` file) looks like below.

```
   42   # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
   43   # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
   44   # the material Icons class.
   45   uses-material-design: true
   46 
   47   # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
   48   # assets:
   49   #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
   50   #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg
```

following the first approach(please see above 2 methods) uncommenting line 48 - 50 won't bring the `assets`(*line 48*) aligned with `uses-material-design: true`(*line 45*) block.

if you follow the second approach there is a great chance you are going to mess up the alignment.

For me I trusted the reformat code option(which available in both VS code and Android Studio) and it's failed me. So I had to correct the alignment my-self.

The correct code will look like below.

```
   42  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
   43  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
   44  # the material Icons class.
   45  uses-material-design: true
   46
   47  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
   48  assets:
   49    - assets/images/
```

Now the keys are aligned(line 45(`uses-material-design: true`) and 48(`assets:`)) and the error will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

```
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - images/
```